# Correct way to interpret function notation

Tags: functions, notation

This is a slightly difficult question to ask, but I've noticed a few apparent contradictions in the way I've learnt function notation, primarily two things:

We see something like the following:

$f(x)=x^2$, I've always seen this as $f$ is the function and  $f(x)$ is the application of $f$ to $x$, mainly when doing mechanics problems I've seen professors and other students use a notation to represent force for example as $F(t)$=$4t^2$ and will say something like $s(t)=2t$ and re-write it as $F(s) = 2s$, this seems incorrect as $F(s)$ should be $F$ applied to $s$ and therefore not be directly equal to F(t) for all s,t . Is this simply a difference in notation between physicists and pure mathematics or is there something I am missing?

Another small side question I have is based on the notation '$f$ is a function of $x$' is the 'function' $f$ which needs to be applied to a element $x$ of its domain or is the function $f(x)$ which is some operator $f$ applied to a variable $x$ giving a 'function of $x$'?

Comment: See [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/862910/a-question-on-function-notation)

Comment: At least out of context, $F(x) =4t^2$ seems simply wrong: the expression $4t^2$ has no $x$; thus, it cannot be a function of $x$, unless $t$ is in turn a function.

Comment: But in general $f(x)=x^2$ is not an "identity"; it reads as a sort of "definitional abbreviation". We define the function $f$ through the formula $x^2$

Comment: The other issue is due to a sort of "mixed" notation: we have a function whose name is $f$ but we write $f(x)$ to emphasize the fact that it has only one argument. We call $f(2)$ the result (output value) of the function $f$ when "applied" to input value $2$. Thus, $f$ is the name of the function while $f(2)$ is the name of a number. If the input values is unfortunately called $x$, the expression $f(x)$ is ambiguous.

Comment: And see [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/who-first-considered-the-f-in-fx-as-an-object-in-itself-and-who-decided-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout this answer, we're of course going to use the modern definition of a function as a "rule" which has a certain domain and target space.

You're not missing anything, and your interpretation of the function notation is perfectly correct. What is going on is that the other students and Professors are unfortunately abusing notation, where they're using the same symbol $F$ in two different places with different meanings. So, it's not your fault for being confused. It doesn't matter what letters we call things. If $F(t)=4t^2$, then it doesn't matter that you define $s(t)=2t$. We still have $F(s)=4s^2$. That's literally the definition of the notation of functions.

So, how do we formally express what the Prof/students are saying? Well, define the mapping $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ as $\phi(t)=2t$. This is an invertible function with the inverse given as $\phi^{-1}:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, $\phi^{-1}(s)=\frac{s}{2}$. Here, don't pay attention to the actual letters used. I could have said $\phi$ is the function such that for all $@\in\Bbb{R}$, $\phi(@)=2@$, and that $\phi^{-1}$ is the inverse function, which means for each $\sharp\in\Bbb{R}$, we have $\phi^{-1}(\sharp)=\frac{\sharp}{2}$. THe choice of letters has **nothing** to do with the definition of the functions. Of course we should use good notation, but from a logical perspective, there's nothing stopping us from using anything we want (you may want to read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3498849/568204) of mine for more remarks about this).

So, if $F:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is the function $F(t)=4t^2$, then $F\circ \phi^{-1}:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is the function defined as for each $s\in\Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
(F\circ \phi^{-1})(s)&=F\left(\phi^{-1}(s)\right)=F\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)=4\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^2=s^2.
\end{align}
(In your post you wrote $F(s)=2s$, when you probably meant $s^2$). Anyway, this is the correct statement. What this is saying is that if we express $F$ in terms of new variables (i.e by composing with $\phi^{-1}$), then we get the new function $F\circ \phi^{-1}$, which is just the mapping $s\mapsto s^2$.

---

As a general remark, if in some physics discussion, if you're talking about a certain function, and then suddenly we're saying it's a function of some other quantitity, then it means the author has omitted an extra composition in the notation. For example, if you're talking about motion of a particle in one-dimension and talk about "force as a function of time" (in the above example this would be the function $F$), and then in the middle of the discussion, we talk about "force as a function of position" (in the above example this would be the function $F\circ \phi^{-1}$), then it means the author is considering a new function by appropriately composing with $\phi$ or $\phi^{-1}$, where $\phi$ is the mapping from time to position. In your post, you used the notation $s(t)=\cdots$. I intentionally avoided this and called the function $\phi$ because I don't like to mix up the names of the functions with the arbitrary letters I use for elements in the domain/target (such as $t$ or $s$).

Also, it is common in physics/differential geometry to consider one and the same function but "expressed in different coordinates". For example, you might hear about "$f$ as a function of coordinates $x_1,\dots, x_n$" vs "$f$ as a function of coordinates $y_1,\dots, y_n$". Perhaps this might be too abstract for now, but bear with me. The meaning of these statements is that we start with some arbitrary set $M$, and suppose you have a given function $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$. Now, suppose also that you're given two invertible mappings $\alpha:M\to\alpha[M]\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\beta:M\to\beta[M]\subset\Bbb{R}^n$.

Now, we have three mappings in the game $f$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$. We can now construct two new functions $f_{\alpha}:=f\circ \alpha^{-1}:\alpha[M]\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ and $f_{\beta}:=f\circ \beta^{-1}:\beta[M]\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$. We think of $f_{\alpha}$ as "$f$ expressed in terms of $\alpha$ coordinates" and $f_{\beta}$ as "$f$ expressed in terms of $\beta$ coordinates". There is obviously a relationship between $f_{\alpha}$ and $f_{\beta}$, namely
\begin{align}
f_{\beta}&=f_{\alpha}\circ (\alpha\circ \beta^{-1})\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
This is a proper equality of functions, and all the compositions are well-defined etc.

In physics you might hear this along the lines of "if we know $f$ as a function of $y=(y_1,\dots, y_n)$ and we know $y$ as a function of $x= (x_1,\dots, x_n)$ then we know $f$ as a function of $x$", something like "if $f=f(y)$ and $y=y(x)$ then $f=f(y)=f(y(x))=f(x)$". I find this sort of language and notation ambiguous because we're using the same symbol $f$ with several different meanings and also an equality like $f=f(y)$ is actually meaningless (I know it it meant to emphasize that $f$ depends on $y$ but it's just formally wrong).
But hopefully it's clear now that equation $(*)$ is what is meant, and all we're doing is composing the actual function $f$ appropriately.